# Get products of children categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child

I have a model, called Groups, it's self-referential, there are groups in it - parents and children together, linked by `parent_id`. So I can get children of a group and products connected to one of groups, but how can I get all products of parent group through its children?
Here is my model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :products

  validates :id, uniqueness: true

  self.primary_key = :id
end
```

It would be great if, for example, I could call `group.products` and get all products, that are direct descendants of that group and all products of children groups.
It would be even better if I could paginate them with something like Kaminari(or another paginator).

P.S. I tried to insert someting like `has_many :products, through: :children`, but all I get is `Stack level is too deep`...

P.P.S. I can create method that will collect all products in Hash, but I won't be able to sort list of products by title, price etc.

Comment: undefined method for which method? please post few lines of your exception

Comment: well, I added console output, that I get, when try to call `group.child_products`. Do I need to have additional model between `Product` and `Group`?

Comment: @Vimsha Well, thanks for the help. I somehow worked out the source of the problem. But now, when I call group.child_products I get only products, that are descendants of parent's children. How to include parent's own products too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :products

  has_many :child_products, :through => :children, :source => :products

  validates :id, uniqueness: true

  self.primary_key = :id
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how do I implement it? I'm kinda new to Ruby. I tried to call group.child_products, but got "undefined method" for <Group...>

Comment: Are you sure?. i tried this in rails console and it seemed to work just fine.